# Center-Align Items In MaterializeCSS Row

Tags: html, css, materialize

I am trying to align containers within a row created with the [MaterializeCSS](https://materializecss.com) library.
[The documentation](https://materializecss.com/grid.html) does not seem to mention anything regarding centering objects that are already within the row so I figured I would ask here.

Current code:

```
<div class="container" style="width: 88%;height: 100%;max-width: 100%;margin: auto;">

<div class="row" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;">

    <div class="col s6 center-align" id="extra-pic-container">
        <img id="extra-pic" width="100%" src="img1.png">
    </div>

    <div class="col s6 center-align" id="extra-pic-container">
        <img id="extra-pic" width="100%" src="img2.png">
    </div>

    <div class="col s6 center-align" id="extra-pic-container">
        <img id="extra-pic" width="100%" src="img3.png">
    </div>

</div>
```

This is what it looks like currently:
[image]

What I would like (rough sketch):
[image]

Is there any CSS magic that can be performed so that this can be accomplished?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can consider using flex box technique

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flew-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="width: 88%;height: 100%;max-width: 100%;margin: auto;">

  <div class="row" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;">

    <div class="flexbox">

      <div class="col s6 center-align" id="extra-pic-container">
        <img id="extra-pic" width="100%" src="img1.png">
      </div>

      <div class="col s6 center-align" id="extra-pic-container">
        <img id="extra-pic" width="100%" src="img2.png">
      </div>

      <div class="col s6 center-align" id="extra-pic-container">
        <img id="extra-pic" width="100%" src="img3.png">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: As you may have noticed the op is asking fro a materializecss solution.

Comment: obviously you heard his last statement  "Is there any CSS magic that can be performed so that this can be accomplished?"

Answer (score 4):

Materialize CSS has 12 columns in a grid. You can use offset to skip any number of columns from the left or start point.

```
<div class="col s6 offset-s6"><span class="flow-text">6-columns (offset-by-6)</span></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I never used materializecss before, however it's like their grid system is exactly like bootSrap which i'm familiar with.

materializecss has 12 columns grid system, and you're setting 6 columns per div which is more than 12 per row, try setting 4 to each, so they be evenly placed.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">

<div class="container" style="width: 88%;height: 100%;max-width: 100%;margin: auto;">

  <div class="row" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;">

    <div class="col s4 center-align" id="extra-pic-container">
      <img id="extra-pic" width="100%" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    </div>

    <div class="col s4 center-align" id="extra-pic-container">
      <img id="extra-pic" width="100%" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    </div>

    <div class="col s4 center-align" id="extra-pic-container">
      <img id="extra-pic" width="100%" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

---

on the other hand of centering items in a grid layout, if you only have 3 divs but only `s2` on each this means your populating 6 columns and 6 are left, you only have to offset the first div by half the amount which is 3.

```css
.row {
  border: 1px solid;
  /* To see the effect */
}

.container>.row>div {
  height: 100px;
}

.container>.row>div:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: red;
}

.container>.row>div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: blue;
}

.container>.row>div:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">

<div class="container">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col s2 offset-s3" id="extra-pic-container">
    </div>
    <div class="col s2" id="extra-pic-container">
    </div>
    <div class="col s2 " id="extra-pic-container">
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the col.div you need to set:

```
float: none;
margin: 0 aut;
```